# What is the difference between Trap and Drill?

Tags: genre

What is the difference between the "Trap" and "Drill" subgenres of rap music?  Both sound very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Trap" music is a primarily southern subgenre of rap, lyrically oriented around drug dealing, characterized by rapid hi-hats, and popularized by Atlanta rapper T.I.'s album *Trap Muzik*.

"Drill" is a Chicago based subgenre of Trap that emerged more recently.

> Drill lyrics typically reflect life on the streets, and tend to be gritty, violent, realistic and nihilistic. Drill rappers use a grim, deadpan delivery, often filtered through Auto-Tune... Though it bears many similarities to trap music, the speed of a drill beat is generally slower with a moderate tempo, having about 60 to 70 beats per minute.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill_music

There is also a similar, UK-based variant called "UK Drill."